# Xcode7 Beta 6 - Invalid WatchKit Support on app store submission

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, ios9

We've been using Test Flight to test our internal builds. Today, we upgraded to El Capitan Beta 7 and Xcode7 beta 6. After also upgrading Parse SDK and making some small swift syntax changes (advance -> advancedBy), we tried to submit a build to the app store and are getting the following error email AFTER the submission succeeds.

**Invalid WatchKit Support** - The bundle contains an invalid implementation of WatchKit. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or pre-release tools. Visit developer.apple.com for more information.

We haven't made any changes to the watchkit app or extension since our last successfully distributed build on Xcode7 beta 5 & El Cap beta 6. We've tried builds with the "Include bitcode" checkbox and without and still get the same invalid binary email.

The embedded watchkit app is still a WatchOS 1.0 app, so it hasn't been upgraded to 2.0, but builds prior to the Xcode 7 beta 6 upgrade were working just fine.

Any ideas of what I should be checking? I've verfied all of the Latest SDK settings are the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error was fixed with the release of the Xcode 7 GM.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15844
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46697